# GRUB can't find Ubuntu running grub-install /dev/sda

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount

I think I messed up. I needed to join root partition and home partition, so I booted live CD and copied root content into home partition, then deleted root partition. I changed fstab to mount sda4 (which is the old home partition) on / and rebooted. Of course it sent me to Grub rescue mode and I had to run

```
set prefix=(hd0,msdos4)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,msdos4)
insmod normal
normal
```

Then when I tried to boot Ubuntu it told me that the partition didn't exist followed by the UUID of the old root partition so I opened commands of Ubuntu (by pressing c) and substituted all the UUIDs with the new one and all the msdos3 with msdos4 then it booted correctly. So I ran in the terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

To save the changes made to grub.cfg
When I rebooted to check if everything was right it sent me again to grub rescue mode and I had to set again root and prefix. I tried to run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

To reinstall Ubuntu on grub, it says "no errors" but running again

```
sudo update-grub
```

It outputs only "Windows 10 found on sda1"
Thanks for your help

Comment: Update grub only updates menu, you probably needed a full reinstall of grub to update MBR or UEFI settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by boot repair, I don't know what it did but it worked